# mouse position control can't transform projection from epsg2332 to epsg4610 with v5.2.0

Tags: openlayers

In `ol.proj.js` scripts, there are some difference between v5.2.0 and v4.6.5. In the function `getTransformFromProjections`, at v5.2.0 there are less code than v4.6.5 to define own projecion:

```js
if (ol.ENABLE_PROJ4JS && !transform) {
  var proj4js = ol.proj.proj4.get();
  if (typeof proj4js == 'function') {
    var sourceDef = proj4js.defs(sourceCode);
    var destinationDef = proj4js.defs(destinationCode);

  if (sourceDef !== undefined && destinationDef !== undefined) {
    if (sourceDef === destinationDef) {
      ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([destinationProjection, sourceProjection]);
    } else {
      var proj4Transform = proj4js(destinationCode, sourceCode);
      ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(destinationProjection, sourceProjection,
          proj4Transform.forward, proj4Transform.inverse);
    }
    transform = ol.proj.transforms.get(sourceCode, destinationCode);
  }
 }
}
```

as you can see, in v5.2.0, those codes are gone. Due to this case, my mouse position control doesn't work while I use epsg2332 with map projection and epsg4610 for mouse position control. I can't get normal lat and lon but epsg2332 coordinate. Is there some new method or function to solve this problem?

Comment: In OL5 you need to register proj4 as in http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html  ( the full build sysntax is `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);` )

Comment: @Mike thank you, I'll try it

Comment: @Mike Thanks again, it works for me. sorry for reply you so late.